# C# & SQL Server : how can l use my dynamic buttons in sql

Tags: c#, sql-server, button, dynamic

I am doing cinema reservation system. I created dynamic buttons as 7 x 5. They appear when I run the program.

Let's say dynamic buttons are seat. There are 5 columns and 7 rows. I created a table in SQL Server named `Saloon1` and it has 35 items (A1, A2, B3, C5, D7 (seat numbers))

```
seatNumber (nvarchar)
isReserved (bit)
```

For example, when I click seat (button) `B3` and the `Reserve` button, I want to update `isReserved` to 1 for `B3` in the table and I want to change color of that seat (button) to red. When I open reservation window again, all reserved seats need to be shown in red (I think I need to create a `Saloon1` class and make those 2 variables (`seatNumber` and `isReserved`) static.

Like this:

```
public class Saloon1
{
    public Saloon1()
    { }

    private static string _seatNumber;

    public static string SeatNumber
    {
       get { return Saloon1._seatNumber; }
       set { Saloon1._seatNumber = value; }
    }

    private static bool _isReserved;

    public static bool IsReserved
    {
        get { return Saloon1._isReserved; }
        set { Saloon1._isReserved = value; }
    }
}
```

Am I right ?

Here is what I did for dynamical seats (buttons)

```
public Reservation()
{
        InitializeComponent();
        create_array_buttons(7, 5, 50, 30, 70, 20, 100, 93);
}


void create_Button(string name, int x_size, int y_size,  int x_location, int y_location)
{
        Button mybutton = new Button();
        mybutton.Name = name;
        mybutton.Width = x_size;
        mybutton.Height = y_size;
        mybutton.BackgroundImage = Resource1.SeatAvailable; // background is green if seat is available.
        mybutton.Location = new Point(x_location, y_location);
        mybutton.Click += new EventHandler(mybutton_Click);
        this.Controls.Add(mybutton);
}

void create_array_buttons(int x_num_buttons, int y_num_buttons, int sizeX, int sizeY, int x_offset, int y_offset, int location_x, int location_y)
{
        int button_number = 1;

        for (int x = 0; x < x_num_buttons; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < y_num_buttons; y++)
            {
                create_Button("seat" + Convert.ToString(button_number), sizeX, sizeY, (x * sizeX) + x_offset * x + location_x, (y * sizeY) + y_offset * y + location_y);

                button_number++;
            }
        }
}

protected void mybutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Button button = sender as Button;
        button.BackgroundImage = Resource1.SeatSelected; // background will be gray when clicked
}
```

Comment: Is it working?   Are you getting an error?   What exactly is your question?

Comment: Sorry, i am a little bit nervous :) The example is question actually. For example, when I click seat (button) B3 and the Reserve button, I want to update isReserved to 1 for B3 in the table and I want to change color of that seat (button) to red. When I open reservation window again, all reserved seats need to be shown in red.  This is what i couldn't do :(   i created dynamic buttons but i don't know how to assign sql code on one of them

Comment: That's a very broad topic, are you stuck on a particular part of it?

Comment: So, l dont know how to explain clearly.  How would you do this reservation part if you would code this cinema reservation system? Would you use dynamic buttons ?